# $.ajax get not receiving data from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've debugged this and the Controller is returning data to the $.ajax call for some reason the data doesn't get returned to the $.ajax function.

```
function UpdateItem() {
var name = $("#UpdateInput").val();
var item = [];
item = { Name: name, Key: updateKey };
if (item.Name != "--Select Item--" && item.Key != "--Select Item--") {
    var url = "api/todo/" + item.Key;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        async: false,
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
    })
    .done(function () {
        $("#UpdateInput").val("");
        UpdateItemRow();
    })
}
}

function UpdateItemRow() {
var url = "api/todo/" + updateKey;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: true,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.Name);
        $("#KeyButton").val(data.Key);
        $("#KeyLabel").html(data.Name);
    }
})
.error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
})
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
    public IActionResult GetById(string id)
    {
        var item = TodoItems.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
```

Comment: sorry, you can't use same controller for PUT and GET method. You must have two different actions. can you post your controller with PUT method?

Comment: PUT and GET on the same WebAPI Controller work fine singly, but there seems to be some kind of problem calling them one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting the cache to false in the $.ajax call worked

```
cache: false
```

I was also using Visual Studio 2015 Release Candidate and there were bugs that changing the port resolved. So it could have been a bug in Visual Studio or IIS. It's an ambiguous answer, but you could try all the suggested solutions if you encounter this problem. Sorry for not providing a precise answer. ))

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
```

from your action and put

```
[HttpGet]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PUT Controller:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody] TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item == null || item.Key != id)
        {
            return HttpBadRequest();
        }

        var todo = TodoItems.Find(id);
        if (todo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        TodoItems.Update(item);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
```

Comment: The GET simply doesn't return updated data after the PUT until the browser is refreshed. Is it possible the GET call is cached?